# how I be sure the HTTP request comes from my site

Tags: node.js, angular, http

now I have backend(Nodejs) and front-end(Angular) apps and I doing many Http requests.
from front-end > to > back-end,
so my my question how I be sure is this request comes from my front-end not from outside !?

Comment: you can set `access-control-allow-origin` header to specific `URL` on your nodejs server, checkout [this link](https://jonathanmh.com/how-to-enable-cors-in-express-js-node-js/)

Comment: @PankajParkar Someone could still send in a request using Postman, or another utility

Comment: If you need to do this securely you should lock down the back end to only accept data from the localhost & have a web server handling the actual requests over HTTPS using some form of authentication (Oauth, Mutual Auth etc).

Comment: if your client's browser, eventually needs to make a call to an API, there is no way you can stop him from doing so directly or through a tool. if you wish to block access to your services from other sources, the only way i can think of is rendering content from the server and then handing it to the client. there are ways to "pair" requests from certain pages, meaning one can access an endpoint if request origin is <your site url> but this can easily be forged.

Comment: thanks guys , so form yours words there isn't way to protect my endpoint form stranger http source

Comment: even  is there way to send hidden value inside my http request I check it from my side ?

Comment: what would hinder someone to check out that "hidden value" by visiting your website and having a look at those secret values in the network tab? there is no way to "protect" your api from external calls - and there is no need either. if you need to protect the CONTENT of your api calls, you should handle that by standard authorization pattern. but you can and should not protect your calls themselves

Comment: all routes on your node app are exposed within the network - there is no way to block that - however there is way to protect it - using various authentication/authorization mechanisms like user/pwd and session OR user/pwd and JWT token etc., Now if you want your App to be only accessed by a given IP/range - that can be done by whistling that IP/range at firewall level .

Comment: okay , thanks guys for your helping